# problem with QPropertyAnimation in Qt

Tags: qt, animation

i have a problem with QPropertyAnimation in Qt

my code:

```
QString my_text = "Hello Animation";
        ui->textBrowser->setText((quote_text));
        ui->textBrowser->show();
        QPropertyAnimation animation2(ui->textBrowser,"geometry");
        animation2.setDuration(1000);
        animation2.setStartValue(QRect(10,220/4,1,1));
        animation2.setEndValue(QRect(10,220,201,71));
        animation2.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);
        animation2.start();
```

till now it seems very good , but the problem is that i can see this animation only when i show a message box after it .

```
        QMessageBox m;
        m.setGeometry(QRect(100,180,100,50));
        m.setText("close quote");
        m.show();
        m.exec();
```

when i remove the code of this message box , i can't see the animation anymore.
the functionality of the program doesn't require showing this MessageBox at all.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an update problem.  Could you try to connect the valueChanged() signal of QPropertyAnimation to an update() call in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code for the animation that you present is inside a larger chunk of code where the control doesn't get back to the event loop (or the event loop hasn't started yet).  This means that when the MessageBox's exec function is called, an event loop starts operating again, and the animation starts.  If you were to dismiss the message box in the middle of the animation, it would probably freeze at that point, as well.

Comment: Huitt:  yes , that's what happens exactly
any solutions suggested ?

Comment: @belhaouary: You will need to either start the regular app processing before this point (if you haven't), or make it so your function doesn't block processing of events (if you've started event processing).  For the second option, you can either break things up and use timers with a timeout of 0 ms, or you can move the heavy processing into another thread.

Answer (score 0):

`animation2` is declared as a local variable.  When the enclosing function
exits, it is no longer in scope and is deleted.  The animation never runs as
it does not exist when Qt returns to the event loop and, as noted in the `QAbstractAnimation`
[documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#start)
(`QPropertyAnimation` inherits QAbstractAnimation), for `QPropertyAnmiation` to execute, it must exist when Qt returns to the event loop.

> When control reaches the event loop, the animation will run by itself,
>   periodically calling updateCurrentTime() as the animation progresses.

The solution is to dynamically allocate `animation2` rather than declare it as
a local variable.

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->textBrowser,"geometry");
animation2->setDuration(1000);
animation2->setStartValue(QRect(10,220/4,1,1));
animation2->setEndValue(QRect(10,220,201,71));
animation2->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);
animation2->start();
```

Note that this it the same technique is the same as that used in the C++
example provided in the `QPropertyAnmiation`
[documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html#details):

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(myWidget, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

animation->start();
```

The original question notes:

> i can see this animation only when i show a message box after it

This is an interesting side affect of how `QMessageBox` works.  The `exec()`
method executes an event loop.  Since the event loop executes within the scope
of the function enclosing `animation2`, `animation2` still exists and the
desired animation executes.

By default, `animation2` will be deleted when the parent, `ui->textBrowser` in
the original question, is deleted.  If you wish for the animation to be
deleted when it completes executing, `QAbstractAnimation` provides a property
that controls when the animation is deleted.  To automatically delete
`animation2` when it finishes executing, change the `start()` method to:

```
animation2->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```