# PySide QPropertyAnimation Not Starting

Tags: python, qt, animation, colors, pyside

The problem is that when I call `QPropertyAnimation.start()`, nothing happens.

Color is the property I'm animating and button is the class.

```
class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,text="",parent=None):
        super(Button,self).__init__(text,parent)
        # ...
        self.innercolor = QColor(200,0,20)

    def setcolor(self,value): self.innercolor = value
    def getcolor(self): return self.innercolor
    color = Property(QColor,getcolor,setcolor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.fillRect(self.rect(),self.color)
        # ...
        p.end()

    def animated(self,value): print "animating"; self.update()

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        ani = QPropertyAnimation(self,"color")
        ani.setStartValue(self.color)
        ani.setEndValue(QColor(0,0,10))
        ani.setDuration(2000)
        ani.valueChanged.connect(self.animated)
        ani.start()
        print ani.state()
        return QPushButton.enterEvent(self, event)
```

I'm confused because `"animating"` never prints out, but `ani.state()` says the animation is running.

I'm not asking to debug my code or anything, but I think there must be something I'm missing, either in my code or in my understanding of the use of `QPropertyAnimation`.

I've searched google for an answer, but nothing came up, nothing relevant to me anyway. The closest I found was [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850957/problem-with-qpropertyanimation-in-qt),  but I still couldn't turn that into an answer for myself. I also saw something about a custom interpolator, do I need to make a custom interpolator, if so, how do I do that.

Comment: The referenced question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850957/problem-with-qpropertyanimation-in-qt/55056534#55056534, has the same problem except it is a C++ local variable that goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool code. It almost works, but the animation isn't persisting past the enterEvent (although I don't entirely understand the mechanics.) If you change

```
ani = QPropertyAnimation(self,"color")
```

to

```
self.ani = QPropertyAnimation(self, "color")
# etc
```

then it will work.

Comment: Thats interesting, I'd love to know why the animation has to be a property of the object. Could it have something to do with `ani` not being available outside the scope of `enterEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused because "animating" never prints out, but ani.state() says the
>   animation is running.

At the point of the `print`, the anmiation exists and is running.  When Python
returns from `enterEvent`, `ani` goes out of scope.  As there are no other
reference to the object, Python garbage collects the object assuming there is
no need to maintain an object that is not referenced.  Since the object is
deleted, the animation never executes.

> Thats interesting, I'd love to know why the animation has to be a property
>   of the object.

The accepted answer changes `ani` to `self.ani`.  This change provides a
refrence to the object outside the scope `enterEvent`.  In the corrected code,
when `enterEvent` exits, the object maintains a reference to `ani` and it is
no longer garbage collected due to the additional reference.  It exists when Qt
returns to the event loop and the animation successfully executes.