# What property supported in QPropertyAnimation to be animated?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, pyqt4, pyside

I am learning Qt and think animating button things are important. I am trying to create my custom QPushButton class which reimplement mouse enter & leave event and use qt animation framework. [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html)

```
QPropertyAnimation(QObject * target, const QByteArray & propertyName, QObject * parent = 0)
```

So if i want to animate its size, i can use "geometry" as propertyName
but it confuses me when i wanna change both **text color** and **background color** too... what should i put as `propertyName`? been searching anywhere but didn't find any documentations about what property i could animate and how it is named in `propertyName` constructor argument.

Expected answer would be all possible parameter Like "geometry" in `QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self,"geometry")` (pyqt4/pyside)

I use PyQt4 but I can use PySide & Qt4.8 C++ too so answer in any of those libraries will be okay (gonna learn them all)

Edit:

I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291726/pyside-qpropertyanimation-not-starting) using "color" and it changes whole pushbutton color (background color), still don't know how to get text visible & animate the text-color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text color and background color are not Qt properties. So you can't animate them using `QPropertyAnimation`.

You can find the list of `QWidget` properties in the appropriate section of the official documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html

If you want to dynamically change some arbitrary attributes like text color, you can launch a `QTimer` and perform necessary operations in a slot connected to the timer `timeout` signal.

---

--upd--

In C++ Qt you can't animate 'color' property because there is no such property. If you try to do it, you'll get the following warning in the console:

```
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property color of your QObject
```

---

As a subclass of `QVariantAnimation`, `QPropertyAnimation` does not support all `QVariant` property types. Supported types are listed [in the doc:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariantanimation.html)

> Not all QVariant types are supported. Below is a list of currently
>   supported QVariant types:
>
> Int 
>   UInt  
>   Double  
>   Float  
>   QLine  
>   QLineF  
>   QPoint  
>   QPointF  
>   QSize  
>   QSizeF  
>   QRect 
>   QRectF  
>   QColor

If you want to animate a property of some other type, you should register an interpolator function for it:

```
QVariant cursorInterpolator(const QCursor &start, const QCursor &end, qreal progress)
{
    ...
    return QCursor(...);
}
...
qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QCursor>(cursorInterpolator);
```

Comment: yes it is not a Qt property, but i think in animation framework it uses different kind of property, as there is no way it can animate "cursor" even though cursor is qt property. And after all what possible values can i pass to `propertyName` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add "color" to Qt property system for you app. Just add code

```
Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)
```

in class widget you want to animate and add these two methods `color()` and `setColor()` in class.
And don't forget to make an updating via `update()` in settter.